# If a sum converges absolutely, must sums of its individual even and odd terms converge as well?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $A_n = \sum a_n$ be a sum that converges absolutely.

This sum can be separated into its even terms and odd terms, $\sum a_n=\sum a_{2n}+\sum a_{2n+1}$, but, must each individual sub-series converge on its own? In other words, if $\sum(|a_n|)$ converges, does it imply that individually, $\sum a_{2n+1}$ converges or that $\sum a_{2n }$ converges?

Comment: You could use the monotone convergence theorem for this.

Comment: But there's no certainty or criteria that any of the sequences must be monotone, so how could that be useful? You could have a series that acts sinusoidal and decays with its sums converging absolutely.

Comment: Absolute convergence means you can assume each $a_n \geq 0$

Comment: You can still just displace a sinusoidal sequence above 0 and then divide it by something that allows the sums to converge. $\cos(n)+2$ is such a sequence. Also, that isn't what absolutely convergence means, it just means that the sum of the absolute value of the terms converges, it doesn't mean you get to assume every term of the sequence is always non-negative.

Comment: It doesn't matter tho

Comment: It does. You said $a_n$ is greater than or equal to 0, but that is false, not every sequence is greater than or equal to 0 just because its absolute value is, so why should I trust you at this point? $|(-1)^n|$ is greater than or equal to 0, but $(-1)^n$ can be less than 0.

Comment: Absolute convergence means instead of working with the series $\sum\limits_n a_n$, you can work with the series $\sum\limits_n |a_n|$ where indeed all terms in the sum are nonnegative.  See my answer

Answer (score 3):

The monotone convergence theorem says if $0 \leq c_n \leq d_n$, and $\sum d_n$ converges, then so does $\sum c_n$.

Assume $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely.  This means that $\sum\limits_n |a_n|$ converges.  To show that, say, $\sum\limits a_{2n+1}$ converges, define $b_n$ by

$$b_n = \begin{cases} a_n & \textrm{ if $n$ is odd} \\ 0 & \textrm{ if $n$ is even} \end{cases}$$
Then $\sum\limits_n |a_{2n+1}| = \sum\limits_n |b_n|$ converges by the monotone convergence theorem, because $|b_n| \leq |a_n|$ for all $n$.

This shows that $\sum\limits_n a_{2n+1}$ converges absolutely, and in particular, $\sum\limits_n a_{2n+1}$ converges.

Comment: How did you determine $|b_n| \leq |a_n|$? If you have a sequence with a sinusoidal quality, you could pick out terms that exceed their same-indexed counterpart.

Comment: Look carefully...

Comment: $b_n$ is just a sub-sequence of odd terms, that condition itself says nothing about the order of their sum in relation to the sum of all even and all odd terms.

Comment: So either $|b_n| = |a_n|$ or $|b_n| = 0$.  Which implies that $|b_n| \leq |a_n|$ for all $n$ as I claimed.

Comment: Okay, so you are slapping a summation operation on both sides of that inequality to show the sum of odd terms is less than the sum of total terms?

Comment: Yes that's right.  The sum of the odd terms (in absolute value) is bounded by the sum of all the terms in absolute value, so the sum of odd terms converges absolutely, hence the sum of odd terms converges.

Comment: I could see how that follows then, but what I don't completely understand is what about the sinusoidal case? If a positive but sinusoidal sequence $a_{2n+1}$ attains certain terms "faster" or before the $a_n$ sequence, shouldn't it be possible that there exists a sub-sequence of a sequence where the sum all the even terms exceeds the total terms at every same index at each partial sum?

Comment: I see what your saying but the beauty of absolute convergence (as opposed to conditional convergence) is that kind of thing never happens.  If $\sum\limits_n a_n$ converges, then of course $a_n$ must tend to zero.  But if $\sum\limits_n a_n$ converges absolutely, that means $a_n$ (and all its subsequences) are going to zero so fast that a sum of any subsequence of the $a_n$ is going to remain small.

Comment: Intuitively it makes sense, but I cannot see it formally. It follows in the particular way that you have defined the sequence $b_n$, so then, how do I know $b_n$ corresponds to $\sum a_{2n+1}$? In general you can just arbitrarily pick out terms to form a sub-sequence, you have to be able to arrange them in a way such that for any given $n$, a displacement of a term in the sequence $a_n$ is greater than that $a_n$th term, otherwise it couldn't tend to 0, so if you can just arbitrarily pick out terms of $a_n$ to arrange a new sequence, but I think that involves creating a new index in some way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying.  Are you confused on why $\sum\limits_n |a_{2n+1}| = \sum\limits_n |b_n|$ in my answer?  Like the sums are reaching their respective outcomes at different rates because $b_n$ is often zero?

Comment: No I just don't understand how it would be impossible to construct a sequence where if you have $n$, its $2_n$ sub-sequence diverges. This can be done in the only convergence case, I just do not understand what the absolute value is doing to the terms to make the difference in how you can arrange a sub-sequence.

Comment: Maybe think of it like this...  You are comfortable when all the terms are positive, right?  Only when some terms are negative and some are nonnegative are you considering the possibility of a subseries of an absolutely convergent series diverging.

Comment: Sure, but why does the condition of terms being positive suddenly change that possibility?

Comment: Let's suppose your $a_n$ are real numbers.  Break up $\mathbb N$ into two disjoint sets $S$ and $T$, $S$ being those $n \in \mathbb N$ for which $a_n > 0$, and $T$ being the $n \in \mathbb N$ for which $a_n \leq 0$.  From what you are comfortable with, absolute convergence should allow you to conclude that 
$$\sum\limits_{n \in S} a_n$$ and $$\sum\limits_{n \in T} a_n$$ are monotone increasing/decreasing convergent sums.  They are basically independent of each other!  And their sum is $\sum\limits_n a_n$.

Comment: The same goes for any subset $Z$ of $\mathbb N$.  It is the disjoint union of $S \cap Z$ and $T \cap Z$.  From what you are comfortable with, the sums $$\sum\limits_{n \in S \cap Z} a_n$$ $$\sum\limits_{n \in T \cap Z} a_n$$ are monotone increasing/decreasing convergent sums.  They are independent of each other and do not affect each other.  Their sum is $\sum\limits_{n \in Z} a_n$, which you can now conclude converges (absolutely!).

Comment: Okay, so absolute convergence implies all of its sub-series are monotone? Is there a proof of that? But wait, isn't it still possible for the sum of the absolute value of terms with sinusoidal-like qualities to still converge as well?

Comment: Not all subseries..just the monotone ones, which I've specifically picked out

Comment: Absolute convergence implies at least some sub-series is monotone, but not all?

Comment: The sums I wrote in the above two comments are monotone because their terms are either all positive or all negative.  That's why I picked them that way.  I don't know about sinusoidal whatever.  Maybe you should ask a new question

Comment: I don't think you are using the same definition of monotone. Monotone as I have seen it defined means each term is greater than or equal to the last, or, all less than or equal to their preceding terms.

Comment: So $a_i \geq 0$ means the sequence $$s(n) = a_1 + \cdots + a_n$$ is monotone.  That's what I mean when I say the series $\sum a_n$ is monotone.  The limit of the series is by definition the limit of the sequence $s(n)$

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Each sum is an increasing function, bounded above by the overall sum, so it converges to its supremum.  The series may not be monotone, but the sum is.